How to get url path for CSS at runtime?
I use CSS Modules.
I don't need resolving of url, but I need replace url paths with my custom function call so that I could get the full url at runtime by myself with my custom logic.
For example,
"background-image: url(/img/image.png)"

should turn into:
"background-image: url(" + myLoader.get('/img/image.png') + ")"

Because of specific image organization I can't use only one generated variant of url after build.
I have to define url at runtime.
I tried such config:
test: /\.(png|jpg)/,
type: 'asset/inline',
generator: {
    dataUrl: (imageContent, fileData) => {
        const imagePath = fileData.module.rawRequest

        return `myLoader.get(${ imagePath })`
    }
}

But it generates a string "myLoader.get", not js expression that executes at runtime.
Thank you so much in advance for your help!

This feels like solving the wrong problem? Just make the server do the routing you need, not your bundler...?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
Maybe I'm really looking at the wrong place, but then how can I dynamically determine, for example, that instead of ".png" you need to download a webp (if supported) or if a picture with a language literal and you need to download only for the current language?

For (1) by having the server pick the right one based on the request headers, and for (2) by having proper language infixes (eg .../en-GB/... or .../zh-CN/...) in your page URLs so that the server knows which language is being requested? Or alternatively, because you're using sessions and you know which language your user has selected.
